# How to buy ETH in big volume?

Tags: transactions, ether

I have a Client who wants to buy ethers, and my client wants to buy in big volume $500k. How do facilitate this transaction from euros to ethers?

Comment: I would rather ask this question over at https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader. Good luck!

Comment: Down vote, because this is not a question about the technology. This would be like asking on stackoverflow about buying a super computer.

Comment: Hi @Victory - Why do you think Ethereum Stack Exchange is only about the technology? Please, raise this in [meta](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/), I think it's an important discussion.

Comment: This question has been raised on meta. http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/338/is-our-site-for-technical-questions-only

Answer (score 2):

Use an exchange, kraken indicates the following in its FAQ:

> Do you offer special accounts for businesses or high volume individual
>   traders?
>
> Yes! To inquire about this, please contact support and ask about our
>   Corporate / Premier program at support@kraken.com